# Storing cookie session data to Jquery using AJAX (Wihout PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint-2010

Having a tough time finding clear information if this is even possible. I am currently running on Sharepoint 2010. Working on a page using the REST method that uses AJAX. I was wondering if there's a way to be able to identify whos logged in? My first reaction was to look for a way to get the cookies session data using AJAX and Jquery. That Adventure didn't last too long.

I was scanning trough the network data of an existing sucessul AJAX request i have on my page. Would there be a way to piggy back trough this same request and ask to provide me the request header's cookie data?

```
loadActiveIncidents: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.basePath() + '/PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, incident) {

                $('#example tbody').append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'> <button class='edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm' name ='btnSubmit' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='"+incident.ID+"'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.Incident + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'><h4><span class='priorité_span'>" + incident.PrioritéValue + "</span></h4></td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.Composante + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control text-left'>" + incident.Description + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control Date_de_début_cell'>" + incident.Date_de_début + "</td>" +
                "<td class='over_flow_control'>" + incident.ResponsableValue + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");   
                })
                IncidentManager.table_conditional_format();
                $('#loading').hide("slow");
                $('#example').show("slow");
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You can then do:
$.cookie('mycookie', 'mycookievalue');

To delete:
$.removeCookie('mycookie');

Comment: Surprisingly worked out great, very simple to use. Yuo made my day! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to here it worked for you Daniel, But I would much appreciate if you could please mark my answer as useful :)