# Setting Cookie in JS for language based on map click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have two pop-up modal which allows the user to select a language.

- **#languages modal**: Allows user to select region and then it'll convert the current page to that selected language.
- **#buy-now modal**: This modal pops up when a user clicks any buy now link on the site.

**If**:

- A user comes onto the site and they have no language selected (using Global English) and they click on a buy now link, it will open the `#buy-now` modal.
- A user comes onto the site and they open the `#languages` modal and then click on a buy now link, the `#buy-now` modal should not pop up (since we already know what language the user is on).

I already have a cookie set for the `#buy-now` modal, called `buyLang`. When a user clicks a buy now link and chooses a language from the modal, it will then set the `buyLang` cookie: `var buyLang = $.cookie('buyLang');`

**To simplify I want to:**

1. Set a cookie called `language-selected`. When the `language-selected` cookie is created (and the `buyLang` cookie doesn't exist), create both cookies with the same value.
2. When the `buyLang` cookie is created, create the `language-selected` cookie with the same value (so user doesn't have to select language again).

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: What did you try and why did that not work?

Comment: @Freddy  I think you may try using this = https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082627/4493831

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit complicated, I don't understand what you mean, but simply if you want to manage cookies, you can use the [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) library.

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectListLanguage">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
</select>

<button id="btnSubmitLanguage">Change</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function btnSubmitLanguageOnClick() {
  const newLanguage = $("#selectListLanguage option:selected").val();

  if (!Cookies.get("language-selected")) {
    Cookies.set("language-selected", newLanguage);
  }

  if (!Cookies.get("buyLang")) {
    Cookies.set("buyLang", newLanguage);
  }

  //   You can set the language of the page contents in server side with reload this page
  location.reload();
}

$("#btnSubmitLanguage").click(btnSubmitLanguageOnClick);
```